# Automatically create 2d map from a video

Tags: video

Is there a software which can generate a 2d map which shows the position of the walls based on a video where I film the interior of a room?

Comment: We can't help you here as we don't have enough information. Please add details of what exactly you want to do, with which software and what the input and output is/should be. Also add more descriptive tags

Comment: like google creates its maps, out of videos

Comment: This is still not enough information. Do you want to create an 3D map as on google earth? Do you want to create a flat map of where the walls are? Or do you mean Google StreetView? Google doesn't create maps based on google Street View footage (Although they enhance it) Google Maps is made with satalite imagery.

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry about being so ignorant.. I would like to create a 2d map of the walls by inputing just a video and no gps position or anything else.

Comment: Great, thats the information we needed. Well, there are software which can do this. One of the swiss universitys in zurich showed such a system two years ago and about all selfdriving cars have such a feature. But often, they use more than one camera and often also lasers. So I am not sure if there is a not very expansive software which can do this. But maybe with the edit someone can help you